# Weird behavior while testing Unity game on Xcode 13.1 and iOS 15

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, shader, ios15

I'm developing a game with Unity, everything worked fine until I tested the game on my iPhone XS which runs iOS 15.1 (through Xcode 13.1).

In particular I noticed a weird behavior with a plug-in I use ([UIEffects](https://github.com/mob-sakai/UIEffect));
it looks like some transparency effects doesn't work anymore (maybe due to the Shaders which uses).

Furthermore, the camera background color is not rendered anymore.

[image]

Instead of showing the background color, I get a white annoying color on the background.

I'm struggling to understand how to fix those problems but as long as I google it, I can't find any tips on what's going on.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing something similar. I moved from Unity 2019 LTS to 2021.2.4. I started seeing it on iOS 15 devices. Yesterday I was testing on iOS 15.1 and it was fine, today I see the issue showing up consistently on two iOS 15.0.1 and 15.1.1 devices (no change in anything else which is strange). Same Xcode build runs fine on iOS 14. (first image is iOS 15, second is iOS 14).

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. It seems to be related to the device's
"light/dark mode". The issue is known and tracked here:

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/gameobjects-are-rendered-with-different-colors-in-the-ios-build

Update:
Apparently this can be fixed by forcing your game to run in dark mode by adding "Appearance = "Dark"" plist parameter in Xcode: https://forum.unity.com/threads/ios-lightmode-bug-filed.1203829/